# Converting data frame's column string values to integers

Tags: r, dataframe

```r
cars <- data.frame(engine_volume = c('1598 ccm','1605 ccm','1900 ccm','1598 ccm','1605 ccm','1900 ccm', '1598 ccm','1605 ccm','1900 ccm', '1598 ccm'))
```

How to convert string values from `engine.volume` to integers?

Answer (score 3):

`readr` has a convenient function `parse_number`:

```
library(readr)
cars$engine_volume_int = parse_number(cars$engine_volume, )
cars
#    engine_volume engine_volume_int
# 1       1598 ccm              1598
# 2       1605 ccm              1605
# 3       1900 ccm              1900
# 4       1598 ccm              1598
# 5       1605 ccm              1605
# 6       1900 ccm              1900
# 7       1598 ccm              1598
# 8       1605 ccm              1605
# 9       1900 ccm              1900
# 10      1598 ccm              1598
```

Comment: My favorite function `parse_number`!

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```r
cars %>% 
  mutate(engine_volume = str_extract(engine_volume, "\\d+"),
         engine_volume = as.integer(engine_volume))
```

Answer (score 2):

While I prefer `parse_number`, Here is one more alternative:

`\\D` matches all non digits:

```
library(dplyr)
cars %>% 
  mutate(engine_volume = as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", engine_volume)))
```

```
   engine_volume
1           1598
2           1605
3           1900
4           1598
5           1605
6           1900
7           1598
8           1605
9           1900
10          1598
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
cars$engine_volume <-  as.integer(gsub("[a-z]" , "" , cars[[1]]))
```